# How to secure a configuration file in IBM Cloud

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, encryption-symmetric

I have a Flask python app running on IBM cloud. The app needs some configuration parameter which it gets from a configuration file. I need to encrypt the configuration file using a symmetric key. How can I do that and where I can store my decrypt key? Ideally I don't want to hard code it into my code.

Answer (score 0):

12 Factor question. Embed it in the app's deployment environment variables and read the value at runtime.